# Java Eclipse Tells Me that My Method is not Static

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, static, non-static

I do not know if I am missing something very basic or not but I have a static method that returns a static integer which I am trying to assign to a different static integer. My code is as static as it can get yet I keep getting the error telling me, "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getX() from the type KeyboardInput" (name of method and class just to make that clear) It tells me that the solution is to make the method static, but it already is so I'm thoroughly lost.

Here's the code:

Class that uses the method-

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends JFrame{

    JPanel panel;
    ImageIcon imgIcon;
    JLabel label;

    private static int xLoc = KeyboardInput.getX(); // errors on this line
    private static int yLoc = KeyboardInput.getY(); // and errors on this line


    public Window(String name){
        super(name);

        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);

        //addKeyListener(new KeyboardInput());

        panel = new JPanel();       
        imgIcon = new ImageIcon("rorschach.jpg");
        label = new JLabel(imgIcon);
        label.setLocation(xLoc, yLoc);
        label.setSize(50,50);

        panel.add(label);
        add(panel);

        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Class that makes the method-

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class KeyboardInput implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    private boolean goUp = false;
    private boolean goDown = false;
    private boolean goLeft = false;
    private boolean goRight = false;

    private static int x = 0;
    private static int y = 0;

    public static int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public static int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    Timer timer;

    public KeyboardInput(){
         timer = new Timer(100, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            goUp = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            goDown = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            goLeft = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            goRight = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            goUp = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            goDown = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            goLeft = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            goRight = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (goUp) {
            y -= 5;
        }
        if (goDown) {
            y += 5;
        }
        if (goLeft) {
            x -= 5;
        }
        if (goRight) {
            x += 5;
        }
        if (goUp && goDown) {
            y += 5;
        }
        if (goLeft && goRight) {
            x += 5;
        }
    }

}
```

This project is obviously not done but I don't believe that I should be getting these errors at this time, hope to get this issue sorted out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works for me. Clean and rebuild.

Comment: I have and I continue to get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't need static word in the following lines:

```
private static int xLoc = KeyboardInput.getX(); // errors on this line

private static int yLoc = KeyboardInput.getY();
```

Comment: Yes do explain the logic because what is being returned by KeybourdInput.getX() is a static integer , so why removing static from xLoc and yLoc ?

Comment: @salilvishnuKapur, The phrase "returns a static integer" makes no sense.  A method returns a _value_, and `static` is not a concept that applies to values.  The only things that can be `static` are _members_ of a class (e.g., fields, methods, and inner classes.)

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer, but I can't format code in a comment*.

This looks like an incredibly bad idea:

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

    ...
    private static int xLoc = ...;
    private static int yLoc = ...;

    public Window(String name) { ... }
    ...
}
```

You have defined a constructor that lets you make `Window` instances.

The fact that `Window` instances have names and, that they extend JFrame looks very much like an invitation to make more than one of them, but every `Window` instance shares the same `xLoc` and `yLoc` with every other `Window` instance.

What kind of sense does that make?

Comment: I was unsure of the project I was making and thus added the "name" parameter in case I wanted different windows with different title bars

Comment: @nicknicknick111, that's great, but my question is why make `xLoc` and `yLoc` static?  Does it make sense?  Maybe your program only ever makes one `Window`, and so maybe it will _work_ if xLoc and yLoc are static, but would it still work if you decided to change the program to have two or more Windows?  `static` is for things of which it only makes sense to have one instance (e.g., java.lang.System), or for things that aren't even _things_ (java.lang.Math).  There's nothing unusual about a program with more than one Window, so why define a `Window` class that can have only one instance?